# Found 3 elements with non-unique id #agreement#1 Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment, billing-agreements

I have total 3 payment method integrated  on default Magento checkout.

please check screenshot and let me know solution

https://www.screencast.com/t/V0ASd12aGKnP

Advance Thanks

Comment: please share your those payment methods HTML file which should under `vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/payment`.

Comment: But payment method are PayPal Express Checkout , Ebizmarts Sage Pay Suite 1.1.7 and third one is check/money order

Comment: Error seems like agreement checkbox id same 3 times but why magento taking same id

Comment: actually, Magento add agreement section for each payment method and as we know payment method section display block once click on particular payment method.  do you have any customization related payment section or checkout?

Comment: No kunj there is no customization on checkout